# OVS-Bridge cant pass physical interface neither ping neighbours

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openstack

I am Running Ubuntu on my Network Node, where i want to set up OVS-Bridge. I've set up everything as every other guy had in his config, facing that failure. I am not able to ping outside, after adding the external public NIC to the bridge.

OVS-Logs seem fine.. no errors like it seems.

Comment: Did you enable the ping protocol in security section?

Comment: where? why shouldnt it work already? i could ping before i added the port